# How to design a Spark based system for long running, data-analysis tasks?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a system with 250M rows of data (and 100+ columns) stored across several tables in Parquet. The system is designed such that analysts can write queries and transformations in Spark SQL, and those queries will be executed in batch. The system should scale to handle 1,000 such queries/transformations.

Independently, each query runs very well on Spark. The first few queries finish in a few seconds, but as the system runs, the queries begin to take longer. The queries start taking 60-90 seconds, and eventually, the entire system crashes with an Out of Memory Error.

Is Spark designed to handle this type of workload, and if so, what are somethings we can do when designing the system?

1. I have tried to write intermediate results to Hive tables on HDFS and using `unpersist` free the RDDs after each query. However, this doesn't seem to reclaim any memory. Is there anything we can do to reclaim memory on a running spark system?
2. I have tried to `count()` after each query -- to force Spark to execute the plan, but again, the memory doesn't get reclaimed. Is there any way to scope a spark query, ensure that it's executed and results are written, and then reclaim all the resources used during that query?
3. Are there ways to monitor the memory usage? I have looked at `sparkContext.getExecutorStorageStatus` and `sparkContext.getExecutorMemoryStatus`. Both of them show ample memory available (25Gb). However, using `top` and looking at Ganglia graphs, I can see that it's the `hadoop` process that is using the most memory (grows to over 50Gb pretty quickly), so maybe these two accessors on the Spark context don't show that memory?
4. Is there any advice on how to architect a system for long-running spark jobs?

Comment: how to you run these 1000 queries, are these independent Spark Applications or Spark Jobs within 1 application? Are you submitting these jobs using multi-threading in the driver code? How are your resources allocated? Have you checked Spark UI for very large tasks/data skew or memory leaks (storage)? Have you enough partitions? For long running apps, you want to increase the parameters related to fault tolerance (max tasks failure, max stage retries etc). There are many many parameters which you can tweak ..... It's hard to tell whats wrong without knowing anything about your code

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thanks for the comment. They are just submitted through a loop in the driver. Loop 1..1K, and the spark context is passed to each one. I guess this is the crux of it, is there a better way to be running these? Is there a way to isolate, or scope each query so they are independent of each other?